# Laptop has 1 HDMI output, can I connect two external monitors to my laptop with the screens extending

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

This is my laptop (Acer Aspire M5):
[http://www.amazon.com/Acer-M5-581T-6405-i5-3337U-Dual-Core-Ultrabook/dp/B00CL8FW4S/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1375995507&sr=1-3&keywords=acer+aspire+m5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CL8FW4S)

I have a external monitor I hooked up via HDMI, but I recently inherited another monitor of the same resolution, with HDMI capability as well.  Is there a way I can have 3 extending monitors, or will it not work due to something with the video driver?  I'm not too knowledgeable in this area, and I've exhausted a lot of time researching, so thanks a lot to anyone who can help shed any light on this subject :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the second external monitor was going to simply be a mirror of the first, then you could use an HDMI splitter.

But to extend your desktop, not just with another cable. You would need 2 HDMI ports on the laptop to support this. The OS needs to uniquely identify each extended display to function correctly. You could use a USB graphics adapter to extend with the extra monitor, though I hear performance of those can be hit and miss

Comment: Yeah that's what my research is looking like. I'd like to avoid the USB adapter :\

Comment: I've heard that USB 3.0 graphics adapters can handle 1080p screens with good results. USB 2.0 ones are acceptable for work, but not for movies/gaming.

Answer (score 1):

The Matrox Multi Monitor adapter accepts DVI which is easily converted from HDMI.  This will work:

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/

Costs roughly $300, not exactly optimal, plus it just takes the full resolution and spreads it across your screens.  Allows up to 3 external monitors.